# PHP & SQL SERVER 2012 Why is this occuring?

Tags: php, sql-server

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO newuserformtable (First Name, Last Name, Title) VALUES ('Alex', 'Picone', 'CEO')";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
$params = array(1, "some data");
if( $stmt === false ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

This code gives me this error

```
"Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => 
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Name'.
 [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Name'. ) ) "
```

Comment: There is problem in your table's column name, Shouldn't have space like First Name,rename it like first_name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert data like this

```
INSERT INTO newuserformtable ([First Name], [Last Name], [Title]) VALUES ('Alex', 'Picone', 'CEO')
```

If you are putting spaces in your column, above is the syntax for insert query.

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes in column name as it is having space in between

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO newuserformtable ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Title') VALUES      ('Alex', 'Picone', 'CEO')";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
$params = array(1, "some data");
if( $stmt === false ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO newuserformtable (`First Name`, `Last Name`, `Title`) VALUES ('Alex', 'Picone', 'CEO')";
```